# How to install Tizen SDK and configure Titanium environment?

Tags: titanium, tizen

please help me out. i have sent full day to get it done.

I get an error like Unable to launch due to missing configuration for SDK or keystore settings in Tizen preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the exact answer at http://www.tizentips.com/tutorials/how-to-install-tizen-sdk-and-configure-titanium-environment/62/

i used that. and it help me lot.